# PowerShell: Create and Initialize a virtual disk with DiscUtils

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, diskimage

When using the [.NET DiscUtils PowerShell Module](https://discutils.codeplex.com/releases/view/78973), I get the following error:

```
Import-Module DiscUtils.psd1
New-VirtualDisk hd.vhd -Type VHD-dynamic -Size 500MB
Initialize-VirtualDisk hd.vhd -VolumeManager Bios

Initialize-VirtualDisk : Path specified is not a virtual disk
```

`hd.vhd` is valid, and if mounted with other tools, is recognized by Windows Disk Management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the proper way:

```
Import-Module DiscUtils.psd1
New-VirtualDisk hd.vhd -Type VHD-dynamic -Size 500MB
New-PSDrive vhd -PSProvider virtualdisk -Root hd.vhd -ReadWrite
Initialize-VirtualDisk vhd: -VolumeManager Bios
```

One can subsequently partition and format the drive.
To format the first 250MB NTFS:

```
New-Volume vhd: -Size 250MB -Type WindowsNtfs
Format-Volume vhd:\Volume0 -Filesystem Ntfs -Label "virtdrive"
```